Animated camera, parented to empty, suddenly moves location on playback
I have a shot I want to add boxes to. I tracked the shot in Blender and created a scene which creates a tracked camera. I had previously positioned the boxes based on an earlier - now discarded - track, but it's from the same shot. The new camera track looks solid, but is oriented very differently.
I moved the cursor to the camera, then created an empty there. I parented the camera to the empty using Parent without inverse (keep Transformation). The idea is to adjust the position of the camera without disturbing the camera solve. However, after much adjusting, when I finally it played it back, the camera jumped off the empty to a (seemingly) completely arbitrary location and orientation. I don't believe it's even the original position of the camera when created from the camera track.
I thought it was maybe a glitch in caching, but the camera does not return to where I put it. I'm not trying to animate it's position with the empty, just adjust the position, and the animate button is not on. Undoing does not affect the problem.

Does the camera still have the tracking constraint, in addition to the parenting ?
